# matrix trigger mode in extendedEmail - Jenkins job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, email-ext

I've a multi configuration project on Jenkins(ver. 2.222.1) We use [JenkinsDSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#)(v1.77) to create the free-style jobs from the groovy scripts. Email notifications is with [extendedEmail](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#documentation)(v2.69)
It seems like trigger mode for notifications cannot be specified in the groovy script but it could be done via the UI as below(ONLY_PARENT or ONLY_CONFIGURATIONS or BOTH) [image: emailextUI triggermode]

As I see [here](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.extendedEmail), below are the configurations we could specify for extendedEmail in groovy for DSL plugin

```
job('example') {
    publishers {
        extendedEmail {
            recipientList('me@halfempty.org')
            defaultSubject('Oops')
            defaultContent('Something broken')
            contentType('text/html')
            triggers {
                beforeBuild()
                stillUnstable {
                    subject('Subject')
                    content('Body')
                    sendTo {
                        developers()
                        requester()
                        culprits()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does not say anything in case of multi configuration project where I need the notifications to be sent only if parent job fails

I believe it exists on [*hipChatNotifier*](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/Migration.md) where we could specify as *matrixTriggerMode*

[image: hipchatnotifier]

Is there a way to do this via *extendedEmail* publisher as we could do it on the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this isn't supported by the Job DSL plugin, yet.
You can work around by using a custom configure block. For example

```
    publishers {
        extendedEmail {
...
        }
    }
configure { project -> project / 'publishers' / 'hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher' << {
            matrixTriggerMode('ONLY_PARENT')
        }
    }
```

Note the `<<` to append a node to the publisher configuration instead of overwriting it.